# How to do http (ng-repeat) with nested json in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, json, http

My code works only when my JSON is not nested. When there is no "," between data and I use only one block of JSON it  works.

My Angular:

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"> 
</script>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

      <table border="1">
        <tr ng-repeat="thing in info" ng-if="thing.color!=null">
          <td>{{thing.color}}</td>
          <td>{{thing.category}}</td>
          <td>{{thing.type}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="thing in info" ng-if="thing.detail!=null">
          <td>{{thing.detail}}</td>
          <td>{{thing.item}}</td>
          <td>{{thing.value}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <button class="button" ng-click="click()">Button 1</button>
      <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

                $scope.click = function() {
                    $http.get("json.js").then(function (response) {
                    $scope.info=response;

                    });
                };

            });
      </script>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

And my JSON

```
[
  {
    "color": "black",
    "category": "hue",
    "type": "primary"
  },
  {
    "detail": "white",       
    "item": "red",                                              
    "value": "silver"
   }
 ]
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the error what you get?

Comment: It won't display in my browser.

Comment: Hi. Can you check for errors in the console? Go to developer tools and then console. Note: In order to use ng-repeat on an array of objects each object must have the same properties. In your JSON the first object (with color, category and type properties) has different properties to the second object (detail, item and value) within the same array.

Comment: no errors in my console

Comment: I have just tested your code and its working if you change response to response.data i.e $scope.info=response.data;

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked for me too

Comment: No probs :) If you log the response to the console i.e console.log(response); you'll see there's a data property which is holding the JSON you need. :D

Answer (score 0):

Please use `$scope.info=response.data;` instead of `$scope.info=response;`.